# Need query fix and optimization help (that finds max high, max low for WEEKLY stock data and last known closing week price)

Tags: mysql, optimization, groupwise-maximum

Thank you for any assistance that you can provide.  I have a MySQL query that is to provide the weekly prices for a stock. I am not the original author for the script that was written as a solution sometime back. I recently had to adapt it for another need.

I have inefficiently added the closing price for each week (the previous), but I can't get the closing price for the current week until it gets to Friday.  For the current week (top row), it should use the latest closing price given so far in the week until it closes on Friday.

It runs very slow and I am  In this case we can use the example of AAPL if you look at the weekly chart.
[Stockchart of AAPL](http://schrts.co/wEAcGAUU)
The following SQL is intended to provide the weekly (max) high, min (low), and last close for the week (usually this is on Friday, but it could be a Thursday if there is a holiday for example).

```
SELECT 
    my_symbol,
    end_date,
    weekly_high,
    high_date,
    weekly_low,
    low_date,
    (SELECT 
            close
        FROM
            mydb.STOCKS_DAILY
        WHERE
            date = end_date AND symbol = my_symbol) AS close
FROM
    (SELECT 
        wl.symbol AS my_symbol,
            wl.end_date AS end_date,
            wl.weekly_high AS weekly_high,
            MIN(hd.date) AS high_date,
            wl.weekly_low,
            MIN(ld.date) AS low_date
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        s1.symbol,
            w.start_date,
            w.end_date,
            MAX(s1.high) AS weekly_high,
            MIN(s1.low) AS weekly_low
    FROM
        mydb.WEEKLY_LOOKUP AS w
    INNER JOIN mydb.STOCKS_DAILY AS s1 ON s1.date BETWEEN w.start_date AND w.end_date
        AND SYMBOL = 'AAPL'
        AND w.end_date <= DATE('2020-05-07' - INTERVAL 1 WEEK + INTERVAL (6 - DAYOFWEEK('2020-05-07' - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) DAY)
    GROUP BY s1.symbol , w.start_date
    ORDER BY w.end_date DESC
    LIMIT 34) AS wl
    INNER JOIN mydb.STOCKS_DAILY AS hd ON hd.date BETWEEN wl.start_date AND wl.end_date
        AND hd.symbol = wl.symbol
        AND hd.high = wl.weekly_high
    INNER JOIN mydb.STOCKS_DAILY AS ld ON ld.date BETWEEN wl.start_date AND wl.end_date
        AND ld.symbol = wl.symbol
        AND ld.low = wl.weekly_low
    GROUP BY wl.symbol , wl.start_date , wl.end_date , wl.weekly_high , wl.weekly_low
    ORDER BY wl.end_date DESC) my_tag
```

** NOTE **: I apologize that I had to use the  `styling for the data output below as other formatting choices caused wrapping or other formatting issues.  I am trying to ensure it is in a readable format.`

The WEEKLY_LOOKUP is a table that contains the START and END dates of each week as reference that represent a week from Monday (start_date) to Friday (end_date).  I am not sure if I need to have something like that or if that is something that can get generated in?

```
# START_DATE, END_DATE
2020-05-04 00:00:00, 2020-05-08 00:00:00
2020-04-27 00:00:00, 2020-05-01 00:00:00
2020-04-20 00:00:00, 2020-04-24 00:00:00
2020-04-13 00:00:00, 2020-04-17 00:00:00
2020-04-06 00:00:00, 2020-04-10 00:00:00
2020-03-30 00:00:00, 2020-04-03 00:00:00
2020-03-23 00:00:00, 2020-03-27 00:00:00
2020-03-16 00:00:00, 2020-03-20 00:00:00
2020-03-09 00:00:00, 2020-03-13 00:00:00
2020-03-02 00:00:00, 2020-03-06 00:00:00
```

This is the result that is produced from the script:

```
# my_symbol, end_date, weekly_high, high_date, weekly_low, low_date, close, current_close
AAPL, 2020-05-08 00:00:00, 305.17, 2020-05-07 00:00:00, 286.317, 2020-05-04 00:00:00, , 303.74
AAPL, 2020-05-01 00:00:00, 299, 2020-05-01 00:00:00, 278.2, 2020-04-28 00:00:00, 289.07, 303.74
AAPL, 2020-04-24 00:00:00, 283.01, 2020-04-24 00:00:00, 265.43, 2020-04-21 00:00:00, 282.97, 303.74
AAPL, 2020-04-17 00:00:00, 288.25, 2020-04-14 00:00:00, 265.83, 2020-04-13 00:00:00, 282.8, 303.74
AAPL, 2020-04-10 00:00:00, 271.7, 2020-04-07 00:00:00, 249.38, 2020-04-06 00:00:00, , 303.74
AAPL, 2020-04-03 00:00:00, 262.49, 2020-03-31 00:00:00, 236.9, 2020-04-02 00:00:00, 241.41, 303.74
AAPL, 2020-03-27 00:00:00, 258.68, 2020-03-26 00:00:00, 212.61, 2020-03-23 00:00:00, 247.74, 303.74
AAPL, 2020-03-20 00:00:00, 259.08, 2020-03-16 00:00:00, 228, 2020-03-20 00:00:00, 229.24, 303.74
AAPL, 2020-03-13 00:00:00, 286.44, 2020-03-10 00:00:00, 248, 2020-03-12 00:00:00, 277.97, 303.74
AAPL, 2020-03-06 00:00:00, 304, 2020-03-03 00:00:00, 277.72, 2020-03-02 00:00:00, 289.03, 303.74
AAPL, 2020-02-28 00:00:00, 304.18, 2020-02-24 00:00:00, 256.37, 2020-02-28 00:00:00, 273.36, 303.74
AAPL, 2020-02-21 00:00:00, 324.65, 2020-02-20 00:00:00, 310.5, 2020-02-21 00:00:00, 313.05, 303.74
AAPL, 2020-02-14 00:00:00, 327.22, 2020-02-12 00:00:00, 313.85, 2020-02-10 00:00:00, 324.95, 303.74
AAPL, 2020-02-07 00:00:00, 325.22, 2020-02-06 00:00:00, 302.22, 2020-02-03 00:00:00, 320.03, 303.74
AAPL, 2020-01-31 00:00:00, 327.85, 2020-01-29 00:00:00, 304.88, 2020-01-27 00:00:00, 309.51, 303.74
AAPL, 2020-01-24 00:00:00, 323.33, 2020-01-24 00:00:00, 315.65, 2020-01-23 00:00:00, 318.31, 303.74
AAPL, 2020-01-17 00:00:00, 318.74, 2020-01-17 00:00:00, 309.55, 2020-01-15 00:00:00, 318.73, 303.74
AAPL, 2020-01-10 00:00:00, 312.67, 2020-01-10 00:00:00, 292.75, 2020-01-06 00:00:00, 310.33, 303.74
```

A few things to mention about the output:

- 1) The first line is the current week.  As each day progresses
  through Monday, Tuesday, etc. it should detect what is the weekly
  high and weekly low and provide the last known closing price.  I was
  able to get the close price to print for the previous weeks as they
  fall on a "Friday".  For example, if it is Thursday 5/7, the close
  for Thursday was 302.92.  I would want it to pull the last known close date that is known for the week.  I inefficiently added the last known closing price so I could just extract it off the result set and programmatically swap it in for the current week to fix the issue, but that is not the best solution.
- 2) You will notice for week of 4/10 that there is also a null space
  there.  I believe that was Good Friday and the markets were closed. 
  To fix this, my thoughts were that I would go back to the weekly
  table to change for that week from a Friday end date to be a Thursday
  end date so it would use that weekly range, but after thinking about
  it more, could get messed up due to the INTERVAL diff adjustment
  being done that always looks for a Friday date.

Ideally, the output would be (with this showing a close of 5/7 as I don't have the 5/8 data yet) that provides the last closing price known or associated until the week closes.  If the query had been ran on Tuesday 5/5, it would have just pulled Monday and Tuesday data and used the last closing price from Tuesday 5/5 of 296.76 since the current week has not closed yet.

(ending week for 05/8 not closed yet as this represents data for the first row from 5/4 - 5/7).  The other 2 rows are a full closure from Monday - Friday.

```
# my_symbol, end_date, weekly_high, high_date, weekly_low, low_date, close
AAPL, 2020-05-08 00:00:00, 305.17, 2020-05-07 00:00:00, 286.317, 2020-05-04 00:00:00, 302.92
AAPL, 2020-05-01 00:00:00, 299, 2020-05-01 00:00:00, 278.2, 2020-04-28 00:00:00, 289.07
AAPL, 2020-04-24 00:00:00, 283.01, 2020-04-24 00:00:00, 265.43, 2020-04-21 00:00:00, 282.97
```

Lastly, this script seems to run very slow as it has to look back 34 weeks at a time for a stock. Not sure how this could be optimized to still provide the data needed but in an efficient manner.

Thanks for any help you can offer. Due to my limited experience and numerous hours trying different things, I thought I should turn to the board to the experts.

With much appreciation.

Comment: Make sure suitable indexes are available and being used. Use EXPLAIN to see the execution plan. Are the rows in week_lookup contiguous? If we are looking for the last 34 weeks, seems like would could add another predicate on w.end_date, not only should be less than a recent Friday,  don't we also know that end_date won't be more than 34 (or 35) weeks ago,  and we can do `w.end_date >=  expr ` which prevent the query from looking back into decades of history... that LIMIT clause gets applied *last*, and that's after the sort, and after getting the min and max from daily,

Comment: Hi Spencer. Correct, the limit could be a different time period.  It could be 52 weeks or 28 weeks. In this case, I had the query provide back 34 weeks of ending data (with the inclusion of what is to be the current week).

Comment: I noticed that the edited SQL above from nbk removes the current week for week ending 5/8.  It only shows starting from 5/1.  I think the date/week change is the issue.  It would need to capture current week and most recent close:  DATE('2020-05-07' + INTERVAL (6 - DAYOFWEEK('2020-05-07')) DAY)

Comment: Would there need to be another INNER JOIN that acquires the last closing price somehow from the current week?

Comment: I checked that WEEKLY LOOKUP does have index for start_date and end_date with end_date being the primary key.

Comment: EXPLAIN produced this:

Comment: MySQL is going to use only a single index for a table; i'd be much less concerned with an index on a small table than i would be on the larger tables. for this query, for the join to the daily table, its equality predicate on the symbol and range predicate on date, so we'd want a composite index, with symbol first. singleton column indexes aren't going to cut it.  my point about the ORDER BY LIMIT is that the query is going to do the work for *all* earlier weeks, and later discard that work.  for performance, limit the work to  `w.end_date >=  lastweek + INTERVAL -34 WEEK`

Comment: I am not sure what to do or the fix is with this query above. I am not very good at sql.  I guess I could try solving this from Java to just pull all the daily closing prices for 34 weeks (170 rows of data per stock symbol), find the max(high),min(low) and the close price for each week. This would just leave a simple query of selecting the symbol,date, high,low,close for each day.  Otherwise, I am stuck.

Comment: I added the following change in this way to just try it:  AND w.end_date >= DATE('2020-05-07' - INTERVAL 1 WEEK + INTERVAL (6 - DAYOFWEEK('2020-05-07' - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) DAY) + INTERVAL -34 WEEK   and then I removed the 34 LIMIT

Comment: How can I get the last current close added in for 5/7 or another day this week so that it is not null if it not a week ending (such as 5/8)?

Comment: And just to observe... your query presently returns an arbitrary end_date

Comment: @strawberry:  i think `w.end_date` is functionally dependent on `w.start_date`, i was thinking the same thing too, non-aggregate in the SELECT list and not in the GROUP BY ... i think the result is equivalent if w.end_date were included in the GROUP BY , but that's a guess without seeing the table definitioan, and based on the information provided in the question

Comment: Instead of playing with `DAYOFWEEK`, you can do modular arithmetic on `TO_DAYS(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:  Follow the [groupwise-max] tag for finding the latest closing price for each ticker.  (The "max" refers to `date`; the interesting value is `close`.)  *Most* groupwise-max algorithms are inefficient.  (Or skip the tag, and go to my blog:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max )

Plan B:  As you store the close for each day, use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to insert or update the row in the `weekly` table.  Assuming the records come in in order, that will take care of getting the last closing price.  If the data might come in out-of-order, it gets messier.